# SelectAll checkbox for the dynamic checkbox inputs

Tags: php, checkbox

I have an "order_details" table with columns "OrderID", "ProductID", "UnitPrice", and "Quantity". Using  the rows of these columns, I use the following code to generate checkboxes. I would like to add a "SelectAll" checkbox beside each row of checkboxes. How can I do that please? thanks.

My checkbox form now looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code: checkbox.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<?php

include 'dbconfig.php';

$subjectName = "SELECT * FROM order_details";

$subject = mysql_query( $subjectName, $conn );
?>
<h2> Select Order</h2>

 <form method="post" action=" ">

 <?php

 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($subject)) {

echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$data['OrderID']}'>" . $data['OrderID'] ;
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$data['ProductID']}'>" . $data['ProductID'] ;  
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$data['UnitPrice']}'>" . $data['UnitPrice'] ;  
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$data['Quantity']}'>" . $data['Quantity'] . '</br>'; 
}

?>

 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can do by using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 <?php
  $i=0;
  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($subject)) {
 echo "<input type='checkbox' id='{$i}' class='check'>"."CheckAll" ;
  echo "<input type='checkbox' class='check_{$i}' value='{$data['OrderID']}'>" .     $data['OrderID'] ;
  echo "<input type='checkbox'  class='check_{$i}' value='{$data['ProductID']}'>" .     $data['ProductID'] ;  
  echo "<input type='checkbox'  class='check_{$i}' value='{$data['UnitPrice']}'>" . $data['UnitPrice'] ;  
  echo "<input type='checkbox'  class='check_{$i}' value='{$data['Quantity']}'>" . $data['Quantity'] . '</br>'; 
$i++;
}

?>

 </form>
 <script>
    $('.check').click(function(e){
      var id=$(this).attr('id');
      $('.check_'+id).prop('checked',this.checked);
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: I get this error, when I apply it. Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\wamp64\www\Sayisal\checkbox\order_check.php on line 31. Line 31  is the second echo line in your code.

Comment: use this.checked for check checkbox

Comment: alert(id); you will get any value ?

Comment: it check all? i think you want  row of checkboxes

Comment: yes, it checks all in a row only. as I needed. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

write all row in div, i think this works;

```
<?php
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($subject)) {
echo '<div>';
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$data['OrderID']}'>" . $data['OrderID'] ;
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$data['ProductID']}'>" . $data['ProductID'] ;  
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$data['UnitPrice']}'>" . $data['UnitPrice'] ;  
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$data['Quantity']}'>" . $data['Quantity'];
echo "<input type='checkbox' class='check-all'>Check All";
echo "</div>";
}
?>

<script>
    $(".check-all").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I updated it, but checkall box appears, when I click it, it doesn't select all.

Comment: did you include jquery?

Comment: i think your code has some errors or tag issues. This sample code works: https://jsfiddle.net/phoeee/bmungk9g/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with jQuery,

Add this outside the `while()` loop:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" />
```

Then in jQuery, add the following:

```
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;                        
        });
    } else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;                       
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Robert, I tried it but it doesn't select the checkboxes.